# MATLAB fspecial and edge function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I applied Laplacian of Gaussian function using MATLAB's built-in function `fspecial`, and then I applied Laplacian of Gaussian using `edge` function. Both are not giving exact same results. Here is my code:

```
clc
close all
clear all
%% LOG using fspecial 
image = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));
sigma=0.5;
window2 = fspecial('log', 2*ceil(3*sigma)+1, sigma);
window2 =  window2/sum(abs(window2(:)));
log_im = abs(filter2(window2, image, 'same'));
%% LOG using edge 
log_im_1 = edge(image,'log');
subplot(121);
imshow(log_im,[]);
title('Using Fspecial');
subplot(122);
imshow(log_im_1,[]);
title('Using Edge');
```

Here is the result of the code: 
How can I get the same result? 
[image: Difference in output]

Comment: First of all, why do you divide your filter by the absolute sum of it's entries? Then: Ed.ge is a *binary* image while *filter2* returns a grayscale image, so you'd probably need to threshold that.

Answer (score 0):

1) `edge` function always returns threshold (binary) edges, and you have to look description of the `edge` function to know the threshold.

2 `edge` uses its default parameter to find-out the edges in image while in `fspecial` you  are assigning sigma value, may be these values are differ, again you have to look the description of `edge` in help.